# Google Cloud Dataflow permission issues

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-dataflow

Beginner in GCP here.  I'm testing GCP Dataflow as part of a IOT project to move data from Pub/Sub to BigQuery.  I created a Dataflow job from the Topic's page "Export to BigQuery" button.

Apart from the issue that I can't delete a dataflow, I am hitting the following issue:

As soon as the dataflow starts, I get the error:

> Workflow failed. Causes: There was a problem refreshing your credentials. Please check: 1. Dataflow API is enabled for your project. 2. Make sure both the Dataflow service account and the controller service account have sufficient permissions. If you are not specifying a controller service account, ensure the default Compute Engine service account [PROJECT_NUMBER]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com exists and has sufficient permissions. If you have deleted the default Compute Engine service account, you must specify a controller service account. For more information, see: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#security_and_permissions_for_pipelines_on_google_cloud_platform. , There is no cloudservices robot account for your project. Please ensure that the Dataflow API is enabled for your project.

Here's where it's funny:

1. Dataflow API is definitely enabled, since I am looking at this from the Dataflow portion of the console.
2. Dataflow is using the default compute engine service account, that exists.  The link it's pointing at says that this account is created automatically and has a broad access to project's resources.  Well, does it?

Dataflows elude me..  How can I tell a dataflow job to restart, or edit or delete it?

Answer (score 0):

please verify below checklist:

1. Dataflow API should be enabled check under APIs & Services. If you just enabled ,wait for some time to get it updated
2. [project-number]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com and service-[project-number]@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com service accounts should exists if dataflow-service-producer-prod didn't get created you can contact dataflow support or you can create and assign Cloud Dataflow Service Agent role, If you are using shared VPC create it in host project and assign Compute Network User role

Comment: Thank you.  Looks like the dataflow-service-producer-prod did not get created.  Is there a way to delete my dataflows?  In the meantime, I opted to using functions.

Comment: No. You can not delete jobs. Though console will list jobs which are created in last 30 days.

Comment: While I've read this in other posts, I fail to understand the logic behind it, especially for "streaming"-type jobs.  Can anybody provide some insight?